# Bash - remove one arg from a list of args

Tags: bash

I'm having some trouble removing a single argument from a list of arguments.

This case is a little odd, because I need to set a variable that holds all ${@:2} args, parse them and set values, then remove any values from the variable holding the list of args if I find any args to be removed while parsing them.

example:

```
INARGS=${@:2}

for in in "${@:2}"
do
case $i in
    -f1)
         VAR1=1
         shift
     ;;
     -f2)
         VAR2=1
         shift
     ;;
     arbitrary_value)
         #
         #remove arbitrary_value from #INARGS
         #
         shift
     ;;
     *)
         shift
     ;; 
esace
done

echo $INARGS
```

So, if you were to run: './myscript mode -f1 value1 arbitrary_value -f2 value2', $INARGS would get 'f1 value1 -f2 value2' outputted, and 'arbitrary_value' would be removed.

I've tried a ton of different ways to do this, and I can't seem to get it right. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `getopts`

Comment: you are missing your ;; after the second shift.  You should clean up the code, indent properly, etc. when asking a question.

Comment: you have set `INARGS` at the top of your script and then you never touch it (modify it's values), you only `echo $INARGS`. It hasn't changed, right? Maybe you want `INARGS='${@:2}' ; .... code ; eval echo $INARGS`, but using `eval` in this case would be shell security risk. Also agree with below about what is the purpose of `${@:2}`. AND the `getopts` will probably a better tool to learn how to use effectively. Good luck.

Comment: I have an answer for this, but I'm confused by your `${@:2}` usage.  That doesn't work like you explained it.  You said it would output `f1` instead of `-f1`, but it really skips the first element.  However, if it did work as you said, you still would not get VAR1=1, b/c your case looks for `-f1` not `f1`

Comment: Explain your objective better, and I'll post your answer.

Comment: @SaintHax, you're right - the example should have dropped off the first arg. The first argument shouldn't be parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the shift, b/c it doesn't work with your ${0:2}.  You'd be shifting off the first arg, while you were processing the 2nd.  You didn't state what this was for, so I've not tried to incorporate it.  If you want to shift off everything but the last arg, then that works (but seems odd)

Instead you just need to reassign the INARG array with the argument masked out.  Easy peasy.

```
var1=0; var2=0
INARGS=${@:2}

for i in "${@:2}"; do
   case $i in
      -f1) var1=1
         ;;
      -f2) var2=1
         ;;
      arbitrary_value)  # remove from INARGS
         declare -a INARGS=(${INARGS[@]/$i/})
         ;;
      *) true;;
   esac
done


echo "var1: $var1       var2: $var2"
echo "args: $@"
echo "array: ${INARGS[@]}"
```

If you do want to shift off all the args but the first, then you need to assign $1 to a variable (e.g. first_arg="$1", shift it off before the for loop, change the for loop to $@ instead, and finally... at the end do a `set -- $first_arg` to have only it remain.

Comment: I wish i could give this answer a bump as well - it answers my exact question, but I think the accepted answer is more commonly accepted as 'the right way' in bash.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you voting it up; you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: That's what I get for answering the question as it was asked :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to do this in an additive fashion, rather than subtractive:

```sh
INARGS=()

for in in "${@:2}"
do
case $i in
    -f1)
         VAR1=1
         INARGS+=("$i")
     ;;
     -f2)
         VAR2=1
         INARGS+=("$i")
     ;;
     arbitrary_value)
         #
         # leave INARGS alone here.
         #
     ;;
     *)
         INARGS+=("$i")
     ;; 
esac
done

echo $INARGS
```

Comment: This is the solution I came up with on my own - it works, but I was thinking there has to be a better way.. i'm just totally new to bash scripting

Comment: There might be a better way, but this is a very common idiom.

Comment: `shift` is probably cargo culted. Since the scan starts at $2, it seems unlikely that `shift` is doing anything useful.

Comment: @rici you're right, i don't think shift is doing anything useful here..

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it was not relevant and removed it.

Comment: @ams, also: `inargs+=("$i")`

Comment: @rici: I don't think that's POSIX compatible, so I don't tend to use it (likewise `${@:2}`), but yes, in a question tagged "bash" you're probably right. /me goes to edit answer...

Comment: @ams: arrays are not in Posix. Once you start to use arrays, you have left Posix behind. The +=() notation works in all common shells which implement arrays.

Comment: @rici: Now you mention it, I did know not to use arrays with autotools. I see that += was added to bash in 2006; probably it will be suitable for use in portable scripts in a year or two!

Comment: This is much more common than what the OP asked for, I have, however, needed to subtract elements.  I have two nested loops, and it beneficial to subtract an element (e.g. file name) that will never be processed from the inner most array, rather than check it each pass.

Comment: @user797963 There *would* be a better way, if `bash` had good data structure support. It does not.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this (untested)

```
mode=$1
shift

original_args=("$@")            # in case you need to refer to them later
args=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -f1|-f2) args+=( "$1" "$2" ); shift 2 ;;
        *) shift ;;
    esac
done
echo "${args[@]}"
```

You'll want to do some research about how to use arrays in bash.

Comment: You forgot the variable assignment for -f1 and -f2.  Also, if someone enters `scriptname -f1 arbitrary_value -f2` you are assigning both -f1 and arbitrary_value to the args array.

Comment: Given the examples in the question, I assumed that -f1 and -f2 both took required arguments. But I see your point.